# Prism IConfirmNavigationRequest

Tags: wpf, mvvm, navigation, prism

I'm trying to implement interface IConfirmNavigationRequest in my WPF app, but can't make Prism call its functions.

In my app there are two regions, Region_1 and Region_3.

In Region_1 there's a FirstView, within which there's a button that's connected to a command in FirstViewModel, that does the actual navigation:

```
IRegionManager irmRegionManager = Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.IRegionManager>();
IRegion irRegion3 = irmRegionManager.Regions["Region_3"];
var viewToActivate = irRegion3.GetView(this.NavigatedView);
irRegion3.Activate(viewToActivate);
```

The navigation exchanges between two views in Region_3, and it works just fine.

FirstViewModel implements interface IConfirmNavigationRequest, but its functions aren't called along navigation, which is simply performed.

```
public class FirstViewModel :
                NotificationObject,
                IConfirmNavigationRequest
{
    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
    }
```

...

I then also implemented interface IConfirmNavigationRequest for ThirdView and FourthView, that are the views between which the navigation occurs in Region_3, but for no avail.

Nevertheless, I implemented interface IRegionMemberLifetime for both ThirdView and FourthView, and its KeepAlive function gets called as expected.

```
public partial class ThirdView :
                        UserControl,
                        IConfirmNavigationRequest,
                        IRegionMemberLifetime
{
    public ThirdView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool KeepAlive
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
    }
```

...

Can anybody explain how to force Prism to call these functions?

Thanks!

Comment: The `IConfirmNavigationRequest` only gets called if you navigating in the same region. So activating Region_3 from Region_1 won't trigger the `IConfirmNavigationRequest` methods.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, nemsv. Do you have any suggestion? If I make Region_1 delegate the navigation (Activate) itself to Region_3, should that solve the problem?

Comment: I haven't used Prism since ages so I don't really know. But maybe this codeplex issue will help you: http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/393261

Comment: I already noticed that link. But you gave me enough to solve this. Sorry you didn't answer regularly, so I can't earn you points. You may still fix this! Thanks again.

Comment: No, IConfirmNavigationRequest may be implemented even by another region. That wasn't the source of the problem. Please see below. Thanks anyway!